# Rails file structure: 2 index lists in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I'm just helping a friend to create a little project. There are 2 models he likes to put in one view (kind of a summary for both of them, see code below)

```
class UnnamedController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @models1 = Model1.all
     @models2 = Model2.all
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<% @models1.each do |book| %>
...
<% @models2.each do |book| %>
...
```

Is that the right way to do it?

How do I name the controller and the view (Rails convention)?

Hope my English is not to bad and Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can call your controller as you wish. Naming things in programming is hard, so you have to choose a name which reflects the page's functionality well.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Ruby are conventionally named using CamelCase, so "UnnamedController" is the proper name for your controller, just like "ApplicationController" also is.

The views are named after the action that calls them, so if your action is called "index", then your view filename should be "index.html.erb".

So you're doing it the right way.